# What is the pseudo code translation of each of the variables in the equation, " *x_ptr = &x "?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, syntax, pseudocode

I am a beginner with the programming language C. I am working from example code online and am trying to analyze the following,

```
int x = 0, y = 16;
*x_ptr = &x
```

It's the second line that I want to make sure I'm understanding syntactically. I have only just encountered the concept of pointers and am trying to crack that nut conceptually. How then should I read the code on line 2?

Comment: Where is `x_ptr` declared?

Comment: There are two possible interpretations, depending on what the code actually looks like. What you've posted isn't valid code.

Comment: Is the semicolon actually where you've placed it in the original code? I suspect not; I suspect `x_ptr` is actually declared in the same declaration as `x` and `y`.

Comment: @user2357112: Well spotted, that's probably supposed to be a comma.

Comment: Dunno about pseudo code, but in plain (more or less) English it's "Take the address of where the variable `x` is stored and store that address value into the storage location pointed to by the pointer `x_ptr`."  (Of course, if it really should be a comma at the end of the first line then that changes things considerably, since `*` means something entirely different in a declaration.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable is a storage location.

A storage location stores a value.

A storage location is associated with a type.

A storage location of type T holds a value of type T.

A storage location is not a value.

Using a storage location to produce a value produces the value stored in the storage location.

Applying the `&` operator to a storage location of type T produces a value. The type of the value is "pointer to type T".

Applying the `*` operator to a value of type "pointer to type T" produces a storage location of type T.

From these facts you can deduce the meaning of your program fragment.

However, your program fragment as given is almost certainly a typo. You meant to say

```
int x = 0, *x_ptr = &x;
```

Let's write that out in a longer form to make it easier to read.

```
int x;
int *x_ptr;
x = 0;
x_ptr = &x;
```

`x` and `x_ptr` are storage locations. The first of type int, the second of type pointer to int.

The value zero is assigned to the location `x`.

The `&` operator is applied to storage location `x` producing a value of type pointer to int.

That value is assigned to storage location `x_ptr`.

If you then said

```
*x_ptr = 123;
```

then the `*` takes the value stored in location `x_ptr` and turns the pointer back into a storage location -- `x` -- and then stores 123 into that storage location.  `x` is now `123`, not `0`.

Make sure you have this *solid*. This is the key to understanding all of C.

Comment: These things you say are true, but perhaps less helpful than they could be. You say the types of `&thing` and `*thing`, but not their relation to `thing`. Also, if the semicolon was actually supposed to be a comma, the code won't dereference `x_ptr` in the assignment, which could be confusing.

Comment: @user2357112: I encourage you to write an answer that is more helpful.

Comment: @user2357112 There's a big difference between *dereference* and *declaration* - in the case of the concerned portion of this answer, it was clearly intended to be the latter.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the intention was the latter. He specifically said that it was the second line of code, and it is very rare to see a list of variables in a declaration like that split over multiple lines.

Comment: It's possible that OP mis-transcribed page 6 of [this document](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~bert/courses/1003/lecture25.pdf). If so , pages 8-10 should be disregarded!

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted doesn't include a declaration of `x_ptr`, but for the code to be valid, the type of `x_ptr` must be `int**`: a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

The expression `*x_ptr` means the thing that `x_ptr` points to.  Since `x_ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer, `*x_ptr` is a pointer to an integer.

Since `x` is an integer variable, `&x` is the address of that variable.  So what the assignment is doing is taking the address of the variable `x` and storing it into the place in memory that `x_ptr` points to.

Comment: Entirely correct - but perhaps it would be less confusing for the OP if you mentioned that `&x` will be of type `int *` in the first place, and thus, for the assignment to be compatible, `*x_ptr` must be of type `int *`, which implies that `x_ptr` is of type `int **`. I think that if you put it this way, it's easier to understand for a novice - because otherwise, it seems like you "guessed" that `x_ptr` is `int **`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, I was thinking about adding an explanation of that, but now I don't need to, because you did.  :-)